# What is the flow of information when deploying an application on heroku servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, repository, bitbucket

According to what I have figured out..
Create local repo => add remote origin and PUSH to bitbucket =>create heroku =>push to heroku from master, from local repo and not from bitbucket

Please verify this flow.

Comment: Do you mean workflow? There is no correct answer. It depends on the project and team. But yes the most common workflow for small projects is that you deploy to heroku from your the master branch on your local machine.

Comment: please refer this link: https://guides.railsapps.org/rails-deploy-to-heroku.html

Comment: @max     So is it correct to say that I don't need a remote origin (like bitbucket) to deploy an app on heroku and  heroku creates a repository of my script on it's own servers?

Comment: @tambakoo you have to add two remote origin (for bitbucket) and heroku

Comment: using origin remote you can push code to bitbucket & using heroku remote, you can push to heroku

Comment: if you choose github instead of bitbucket then you can easily link heroku with github and no need to deploy on both...if you push on heroku then same code automatically push on github repo

Comment: @puneet thanks! Is there a way to sync bitbucket with heroku?

Comment: @tambakoo no bitbucket is not connect with heroku.

Comment: @tambakoo vote me if my answer helps to you. Thanks

Comment: No bitbucket or github or whatever you use to host your repository is not connected to Heroku. Thats where you collaborate with other developers and it serves as a backup. You can setup post commit hooks that automatically deploy to production when you push to Github/Bitbucket but thats usually only done on established projects where [continuous-deployment](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/continuous-deployment/)  is practiced.

Comment: But thats way above your level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this step - `add remote origin and PUSH to bitbucket`.

You add `heroku` as remote url to your git. You can read more about deployment process and what's going in official heroku doc - [Deploying with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to sync my remote repository with heroku?

Comment: @tambakoo you can use your computer for this :) some CI tools like Travis support continuous deploy to heroku from the box.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy a rails app to heroku is ideal. Just go through heroku official document [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5).

Hear I add some essential command, you need to run sequential, after push new changes to git repository.

```
> heroku login
> heroku create
> git push heroku master
> heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Github then you can easily link your Heroku app with Github repo and all your Heroku code automatically pushed to Heroku.

This option is not available for BitBucket now.